# jQuery enter url and loads content into div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I don't know if i described the title correctly ...
Basically i have a jquery script that loads content when link is clicked.

I would like to know to say lets say i loaded /contents/about.php via jquery into the div i specified.

```
<li class="nav__item ">
     <a class="header__link subdued" href="#home" data-target="contents/home">
     <span class="complimentary push--left">Home</span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="nav__item ">
     <a class="header__link subdued" href="#news" data-target="panel/admin/news/news">
     <span class="complimentary push--left">News</span>
     </a>
</li>
<li class="nav__item ">
     <a class="header__link subdued" href="#/contents/about" data-target="contents/about">
     <span class="complimentary push--left">About Us</span>
     </a>
</li>
```

Is it possible for me to enter http://localhost/#/contents/about or even http://localhost/contents/about and it would as the same function as the jquery click load script.
Alternatively is there a simple way to have a back/forward setup in jquery content load?

script:

```
<script>
      $(document).ready(function(){ 
         var trigger = $('#nav ul li a'),
          container = $('#wrapper');
          trigger.on('click', function(){
          var $this = $(this),
            target = $this.data('target');       
            container.load(target + '.php');
            return false;
         });
      });
   </script>
```

Hope it makes sense.

Comment: please add another `a` block to your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var cur = window.location.href;
    var a = cur.split("/");
    var pos = a.indexOf("#");
    if(pos != -1){
        var trigger = $('#nav ul li a');
        var container = $('#wrapper');
        target = a[pos+1]+""+a[pos+2];
        container.load("http://localhost/"+ target + ".php");
        return false;
    }
});
```

Try this, if not useful then i will remove this, cause i don't understand what you want.

Comment: that does not make sense Frayne .... because it's triggered by clicking on a Nav a link. I described i want to keep that function as it is but i need another one where when user enters http://localhost/contents/news it will redirect to index and have something like: $(location).attr('href');

Comment: you want to dynamically load the pages??

Comment: yer ... that function works fine that's for the nav but say if i i click on news it will go to /#news if user reloads or manually entered that url i would like it to load  the attr('href'); into the div on index.php instead of loading redirecting to that page ... if that makes sense?

Comment: it means if your url contain the `#`, then you will load the page after the `#`. say: `/#/news` so load the news like `content/news/`

Comment: that works thanks :) sorry i had a bad explanation of what i wanted, thanks alot